# Terraform - ELB attempts re-create instead of updating

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-elb

Update: `terraform destroy` isn't deleting the ELB and but the apply command attempts to recreate. Just running the command `terraform apply` tries to recreate ELB even though no changes has been made to ELB module.

What would be the reason for it?

Here is the error I get:

`Error: Error creating ELB: DuplicateLoadBalancerName: Load Balancer named myELB already exists and it is configured with different parameters. status code: 400, request id: 123456789-67b1-4fbd-95e3-17f693cdcf75`

Here is the ELB code:

```
# Create ELB
resource "aws_elb" "myELB" {
   depends_on = [
      aws_instance.webservers,
    ]
  for_each = toset(var.public_subnets_names)

  name = "myELB"
  subnets = [data.aws_subnet.public_subnet_ids[each.value].id]

  listener {
    instance_port = 80
    instance_protocol = "http"
    lb_port = 80
    lb_protocol = "http"
  }

  health_check {
    healthy_threshold = 2
    unhealthy_threshold = 2
    timeout = 3
    target = "HTTP:8080/"
    interval = 30
  }

  instances = data.aws_instances.webservers.ids
  cross_zone_load_balancing = true
  idle_timeout = 400
  connection_draining = true
  connection_draining_timeout = 400

  tags = {
    Name = "myELB"
  }

}
```

Here is the data source looks like:

```
# Get Public Subnets ID's
data "aws_subnet" "public_subnet_ids" {
  depends_on = [
    aws_subnet.subnets,
  ]

  for_each = toset(var.public_subnets_names)

  filter {
    name = "tag:Name"
    values = [each.value]
  }
}
```

Comment: Updated the question.. ELB isn't deleting when running command `terraform destroy`. Even other wise, just running command `terraform apply` attempts to recreate

Comment: So you are creating multiple ALBs, one in each subnet? Is it on purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because you are creating **multiple ALBs**, one in each subnet with the same name of `myALB`. This is due to the following line:

```
for_each = toset(var.public_subnets_names)
```

Not sure if this is your intention or mistake, thus its not clear what do you want to achieve.

Update:

You would usually just use [subnets](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/elb#subnets):

```
subnets = data.aws_subnet_ids.subnets.ids
```

where you would use [aws_subnet_ids](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/subnet_ids) to get ids of your subnets.

Comment: So for_each runs resource twice? I thought only count runs resources twice. Here I wanted to loop through `var.public_subnets_names` and get the ID's and insert into subnets. What would be better approach? I've updated the question with the data source.  `var.public_subnets_names` is a list of subnet names

Comment: I didn't use count since count will run resource the number of specified times. It seems like for_each does the same?

Comment: Maybe use a for loop?